# Moments of an exponential sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Let $p$ and $N$ be large natural numbers. I would like to get a possibly sharp asympotic approximation of
$$
\mathcal{I}_{p,N}=\int_0^1 \Big(\sum_{j=1}^N e^{2\pi i j \xi}+\sum_{j=1}^N e^{-2\pi i j \xi}\Big)^p d \xi, \quad \textrm{as}\quad p,N\rightarrow \infty
$$

The integrand can be expressed in a more concise form in terms of sines and cosines, but it does not seem to help. I also tried to attack this problem by viewing $\sum_{j=1}^N e^{2\pi i j \xi}$ as a Fourier transform of the characteristic function of $\{1, \dots , N\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$, but that approach also failed.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: It might matter how $p,N$ are related to each other. What regime do you have in mind? E.g. is $N$ much larger than $p$?

Comment: Integrand reduce to a $p$ powered fraction in terms of $\cos(2\pi\xi)$,  $\cos(2N\pi\chi)$ and $\cos(2[N+1]\pi\xi)$ functions. At the borders $\xi=0,1$, integrand behaves as $(1/2)\delta(\xi)$ and $(1/2)\delta(\xi-2\pi)$ as $p,N\rightarrow\infty$ respectively being $\delta(\xi)$ the Dirac delta 'function'. The leading term asymptotics is $O(1)$

Comment: @mathworker21 I agree that the relation between $N$ and $p$ may be relevant. I am interested in $N$ much larger than $p$ (say $N>p^2$).

Comment: @JorgeZuniga I think the integrand is $\cos(\pi (N+1)\xi)\frac{\sin(\pi N\xi)}{\sin(\pi\xi)}$, so for a fixed $p>1$ the integral is of size $N^{p-1}$, not O(1).

Comment: @Tony419 Maple gives this expression for the integrand $[-1+\frac{\cos(2\pi N\xi)-\cos(2\pi[N+1]\xi)}{1-\cos(2\pi\xi)}]^p$. You are right, the limit is not constant. At $\xi=0$ and $\xi=1$ integrand is $2^pN^p$. Both points are maxima in $[0,1]$. At the limit just these contribute to the integral.

Comment: Isn't it simply a combinatorial problem, number of uples $(k_1,k_2,...,k_p)$ with $|k_i|\le N$ all nonzero and summing to $0$ ?

Comment: @HenriCohen Yes, that's another way of looking at it. But I couldn't solve the combinatorial problem either. Do you have any idea how to count these tuples?

Comment: As a variation of @HenriCohen's observation, the integral is, essentially, the number of points of the $(p-1)$-dimensional integer lattice in the region $\Omega=\{(x_1,\dotsc,x_{p-1})\colon |x_1|,\dotsc,|x_{p-1}|,|x_1+\dotsb+x_{p-1}|\le N\}$. For $N$ large as compared to $p$, this is asymptotically the volume of $\Omega$, which is easy to compute. It should be possible to make this precise using the standard geometry of numbers results on the number of lattice points inside a region.